# What does the database symbol mean in Eclipse icons?

Tags: java, eclipse

What does the database symbol mean in Eclipse icons?

I marked the database symbol in two places here:

[image]

For some reason, the file named ChangeObject.java does not have such icon that
contains the database symbol. What does that mean?

Edit: By the way I use Team Foundation Server for Eclipse.

This is the Team menu I get for that file that does not contain the database icon:

[image]

Thanks

Comment: The files with that symbol are in your version control.  The ones without it are not.

Comment: I use Team Foundation Server. So how do I add that file to source control?

Comment: right click the file and check the `Team` menu option.

Comment: Yes but what to choose then? There are lot of options and none make sense in this case. Most of them are disabled for this file.

Comment: You'll find your answer here although this article uses a different version control: http://wiki.eclipse.org/EGit/User_Guide/Sharing

Comment: Not really. There is no Team->Add in my menu.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Files with the yellow cylinder overlay are stored in your source control system, while files without have not been added. How you add files is dependent on what system you use.

Comment: I use Team Foundation Server. So how do I add that file to source control?

Comment: Right click on the file, and look for the Team sub menu.

Comment: Not familiar with TFS. See if there are TFS related views. Some source control systems have a dedicated view where you arrange a change and then submit it. Perhaps you have add the file there.

Comment: In other words, Eclipse knows that I use Git?

Answer (score 1):

it depicts the project is version controlled.
And the file has not been modified locally since your last check out. & the number is the version number.
The file without the number is newly added, i.e. not version controlled.

to check in to TFS:

> 1. right click on the project (not just a file)
> 2. select team
> 3. select check in pending changes
> 4. now you'll get a window showing files with changes (including new files), you can select whatever you want to check in.

Comment: I use Team Foundation Server. So how do I add that file to source control? And yes that file was newly added, I added a new class.

Comment: @user2381422 for using TFS with eclipse this will help you. http://tfs.visualstudio.com/en-us/learn/check-files-in-and-out-eclipse.aspx

Answer (score 0):

`ChangeObject.java` is not yet added to your repository, thats why it does not have the cylinder icon attached.

You can right click on the containing project or package to synchronise and update your repository with the new files.